# Quartz.NET doesn't throw exception if job instantiation fails

Tags: castle-windsor, quartz.net

I am using Quartz.NET via castle windsor, everything works fine but one of job used Identity dependency and If I do not registered dependency it doesn't throw exception.

registration code

```
 static void RegisterTriggerListeners(IWindsorContainer container)
    {
        container.Register(DefaultInterfaces());
        container.Register(Connections());
        container.Register(
            Component.For<Quartz.IScheduler>().Instance(StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler()),
            Component.For<IJobFactory>().ImplementedBy<WindsorJobFactory>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue<IWindsorContainer>(container)).LifestyleTransient(),

            // See: http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/16/using-the-web-api-dependency-resolver-with-castle-windsor-scoped-lifetime/
            // public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) section near the end of the page
            Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IHttpController>().LifestyleScoped()
            //,
            //Component
            //  .For<IIdentity>()
            //  .UsingFactoryMethod(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent)
            //  .LifestyleSingleton()
            );

        RegisterJobs(container);
    }
```

job that use Identity

```
class ValidationStep : Step<ITransactionLineValidationStep, TransactionLine>, ITransactionLineValidationStep
    {
        private IImpersonatedWebClient ImpersonatedWebClient { get; }
        private ISettings Settings { get; }
        readonly IIdentity _identity;
        private string ValidationAddress { get; set; }
        private const string ValidationResultError = "Error";

        public ValidationStep(IImpersonatedWebClient impersonatedWebClient,
            ISettings settings,
            IIdentity identity)
        {
            ImpersonatedWebClient = impersonatedWebClient;
            Settings = settings;
            _identity = identity;
        }
```

if I commented out Identity registration - scheduler is running fine but stops running using job without throwing exception.
Is there any way I get notified or throw exception if dependency are not registered ?

Comment: See my answer. I also suggest to change title to something like "Quratz.NET doesn't throw exception if job instantiation fails" as its more accurate for the case described...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably not Castle issue as Castle always throws exception when some non-optional (constructor) dependency is missing during component resolving.

What you see is result of Quartz.NET design - if exception is thrown during job creation (using job factory method `NewJob`), Quartz just catch it and convert it to `SchedulerException` (see [JobRunShell line 94](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Core/JobRunShell.cs#L94)) which is later swalowed (see [QuartzSchedulerThread line 420](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/master/src/Quartz/Core/QuartzSchedulerThread.cs#L420)). At the same time, Quartz invokes `SchedulerError` method of any `ISchedulerListener` attached to it's scheduler

Reason for all this is to protect Quartz scheduler thread from breaking the application.
If you only want to check this during development, just configure Quartz logging (uses Common.Logging framework - see [documentation - at the bottom](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/configuration-resource-usage-and-scheduler-factory.html)) and you'll see errors like this in log. Otherwise you can [write your own](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/scheduler-listeners.html) `ISchedulerListener` to handle `SchedulerError` "event" and do whatever you want there...

Note: Source code links provided are from master branch, which is for yet unreleased 3.x version of Quartz.NET but 2.x version works same...